# What does mean connection in jmeter ? Can we get the details of how many connections were made (not the user sample but the connections)

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

What does mean connection in jmeter ?  Can we get the details of how many connections were made (not the user sample but the connections)

Comment: What do you mean connections?

Comment: can you please explain little bit  more

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the number of the TCP connections open by JMeter by invoking [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command in the [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

If you're testing a web application the number of connections will vary from 1 to 6 (or whatever you specify under [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

However normally you should not be very interested in this form of information. My expectation is that you should rather be looking for [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/#Server-Hits-per-Second) custom chart which reports how many "hits" were generated by JMeter during the test execution time frame. The listener is available via `5 Additional Graphs` bundle and can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri,
I want to know that number of threads means(users) = no. of connections ? Or i am interpreting wrongly.
How i can make sure that all users has made the connections and running parallel?

Comment: I have already told you what is the relationship between virtual users and connections and how to monitor the number of connections. If you want to monitor the number of online virtual users - go for [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener which can be installed as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle using JMeter Plugins Manager. You can also consider using [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) results analysis service which provides fancy web view of your load test metrics.

Comment: Sorry @Dmitri .. i could not get understand of "I have already told you what is the relationship between virtual users and connections "
Jmeter makes the same no of connections what ever we specify no in thread group(number of users/ threads)?

Comment: Can you please explain more above